# sed: unable to find and replace

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I am trying to replace the customernumber in my text file with the input assigned to the variable named input. But unable to complete this using sed, Below is the method am trying

```
input=$(cat customernumber.txt)
echo $input
cat CUSTOMER_REPORT.txt | sed -e s/%customernumbers%/$input/g > temp.sql
```

My `customernumber.txt` contains the values `(12345,67890)`, my `CUSTOMER_REPORT.txt` contains the below values:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERNUMBER,ORDERNUMBER
FROM ORDER WHERE CUSTOMERNUMBER IN %customernumbers% WITH UR;
```

I am getting the below error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated `s' command
```

How to replace the %customernumbers% with the value in $input? Is there any other option available other than sed?

Comment: see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your substitution `sed` commands between double quotes

```
sed -e "s/%customernumbers%/$input/g" > temp.sql
```

After debugging a bit:

```
cat CUSTOMER_REPORT.txt | sed -e "s/%customernumbers%/(12345,67890)/g" > temp.sql
```

was working fine so we narrowed the root cause until we reached the file `customernumber.txt` by using `wc -l customernumber.txt` or `cat -vTE customernumber.txt`

after a bit of fixing it works fine.

Comment: Tried the same but getting the same error                                            cat CUSTOMER_REPORT.txt | sed -e "s/%customernumbers%/$input/g" > temp.sql
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated `s' command

Comment: ok let's debug this together!!! ;-) try this command and let me know if it works: `cat CUSTOMER_REPORT.txt | sed -e "s/%customernumbers%/(12345,67890)/g" > temp.sql`

If it works than it means that the problem does not come from the sed command itself but to what is contained in the variable, (example an empty line at the end of the `customernumber.txt` file

Comment: yes, the above one works                                                                      cat temp.sql
SELECT CUSTOMERNUMBER,ORDERNUMBER
FROM ORDER WHERE CUSTOMERNUMBER IN (12345,67890) WITH UR;

Comment: ok then the problem does not come from the `sed` command but from your variable `$input` I suspect there is an `EOL` at the end of it could you do the following command: `cat -vTE customernumber.txt` and `wc -l customernumber.txt` and give me the inputs?

Comment: Great, the problem is with the customernumber.txt file. I have corrected it now and its working as expected..Thank you !!

Comment: you are welcome! ;-) happy to help you!!! Keep in mind to always try to get the problem location with a step by step approach! In the end you will reach it for sure ;-)

Comment: Capturing things in a shell variable so you can then substitute them sounds like a very roundabout way to do things. You should probably be looking at parametrizing your SQL query anyway, which will make all of this moot.

Comment: Tangentially, [the `cat` is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)